# Rails Test helper method accepting ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, helper, formbuilder

I'm trying to write a test for a helper method that accepts a form helper object, is there a way to create a form object within the test?

/app/views/blahs/edit.html.erb

```
<% form_for :blahs do |blah| %>
 <%= my_helper_method(blah) %>
<% end %>
```

/app/helpers/blahs_helper.rb

```
def my_helper_method(blah)
  # 
  # blah is ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder 
  # do something with the form object here 
  #
end
```

So in my test case how do I create the form object? I'm still on Rails 2.3.9.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try using it with a partial first, then get fancy with a helper maybe?  Unless you are doing some fudged up "Model" type stuff, a partial is a great way to reuse form code and easier to test.

helpers are for "View logic" in a way.  partials are for displaying form fields, even ones that repeat.

It could help to see what you are trying to do in a helper that you can't in a partial.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could `require 'action_view/helpers/form_helper'` (which lives in actionpack) in your helper spec which will make the method form_for available.

However I am with pjammer that you should question whether the logic you're putting in your helper_method really belongs there. If you tell us what you're trying to accomplish in helper_method we may be able to give you alternatives that don't require to pass the form object, which is probably a better approach.